# Mathematical significance of upside deviation bigger than downside deviation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I have been searching around for an explanation, but could not find any.

What is the mathematical significance of a sample set's upside deviation (standard deviation of values larger than the mean) being bigger than the downside deviation?

Intuitively I feel that skewness might have to do with it, but I am not so sure.